# quiero añadir un nuevo interruptor relacionado conla depuracion inalambrica en MIUI

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wireless

Cuando estoy trabajando con Android Studio tengo una forma de descargar la aplicacion con la depuracion inalambrica, el problema es que estoy cansado de meterme cada vez a ajustes y tener que activar la opcion. Alguien sabe si existe alguna opcion para meter esa opcion en la parte de interruptores, es decir (cuando bajas la notificaciones para activar el wifi, bluetoth, nfc, ect...) y que se pueda activar y desactivar la depuracion inalambrica.

He probado algo con chatgpt pero me da indicaciones que mi movil no tiene esas opciones, tambien he intentado buscar en github, por si alguien tiene algo pero no encuentro nada...

Answer (score 0):

**Este tipo de configuraciones actualmente ya no es posible realizarlas desde las apps, seguramente por cuestiones de seguridad, y esta característica, no únicamente en los dispositivos Xiaomi que cuentan con MIUI**.
Forzosamente debes abrir la configuración ir a los ajustes y buscar el interruptor de "Depuración inalámbrica" o "Depuración por Wi-Fi" manualmente .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]